# Pin not showing correct location google map api

Tags: xamarin.forms

Hi When I view my map it's just showing me empty ocean but if you put in the coordinates online you will get a valid place how do I get it down to road level. So its shows the roads like in google maps navigation.

```
 public TaxiOrderMap()
 {
        InitializeComponent();
        RequestPermission();

        var pin = new CustomPin
        {
            Type = PinType.SavedPin,              
            Position = new Position(54.7529, -6.01667),
            Label = "Close to me ",
            Address = "B",


        MarkerId = "Xamarin",
            Url = "http://xamarin.com/about/"
        };

        googleMap.HasZoomEnabled = true;

        googleMap.Pins.Add(pin);


}
```

Answer (score 2):

adding a pin to a map does not mean the map will automatically show that pin.  Setting the position of the map is well [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map#map-region-and-mapspan)

```
map.MoveToRegion(new MapSpan (new Position(lat, long), latlongdegrees, latlongdegrees));
```